# How to install python packages in an unstable connection

Tags: networking, python, packages, python3, pycharm

I've been trying to install tensorflow but without success. I suspect the reason is unstable internet connection because I was able to successfully install a smaller package (openCV) minutes before attempting to install tensorflow. To digress, this is what the output of the installation command looks like in Pycharm:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe49aeff2e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe49aeff610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe49aeff8b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe49aeffa60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe49aeffc10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/tensorflow/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

From the output it appears that the Pycharm (or whatever component Pycharm delegates the task to) only tries five times before giving up. Is it possible to change or remove the limit on the number of failed trials before stopping?

Not sure if this is relevant, but the python interpreter in use in Pycharm is the one versioned 3.10.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: don't. Just install it on some machine with stable connection and copy the resultant cache files.

Long answer: what you are trying to do here is basically impossible. You need to download the file to install the library, and if your network is unstable, you can't download the file thus cannot install the library.

Even if the file somehow was successfully downloaded, because of your unreliable connection, the integrity of the file is very likely compromised, and you still can't install from corrupted files.

But on a computer with stable connection, the above is not an issue.

So you just need to use a computer with stable network to download the file and use a USB storage device to move the file to your computer.

`pip` can install libraries from local files, thus you don't need to download the files through unreliable network.

Were it some library without dependencies, you can just download the source (or precompiled wheel) from pypi on another computer and then transfer it offline to your computer, then pip install the local file.

But since you are trying to install such a big library with a lot of dependencies (some of which likely have dependencies themselves), this will not work.

You need to write a program to sort the libraries by number of dependencies, then install libraries with zero dependencies first, then install libraries with dependencies already installed, and so on...

But there's another way: every file downloaded by pip is stored at the cache directory, and when pip install is run, it will check if the file is cached first, and will only download the file if it isn't cached (or explicitly told not to use cache), so if there is a cached file it will use the cached file instead of downloading.

So all you have to do is to find a computer with good network connection, then install Python and then install the library. Now this is the crucial part: you need to locate the pip cache directory on the computer, then copy everything in the directory to your USB device, then use the USB device to move the contents of the cache directory to your pip cache directory.

And then you can install as normal, because everything is cached, pip will just use the cached files without downloading.

One caveat though, the OS and the Python version of the computer likely has to be the same as yours.